AG Grid : change field value when editing in fullRow mode
With AG Grid, when I edit a row in "fullRow" mode, is it possible to dynamically change the value of the next field?
Something like that (I know that it doesn't work, it's just for example) :
grid.editType = "fullRow";
grid.columnDefs = [
  {
    field: "type",
    editable: true,
    onCellValueChanged: params => {
      if (!params.data.name)
        params.data.name = params.newValue + " Test";
    }
  },
  {
    field: "name",
    editable: true
  }
];

When I finish to edit the "type" field, I would like the "name" field to be preinitialized when I press TAB with a value based on "type".
